# How do I make it responsive in a better way without using two media query's combined with flex box, it was quite a struggle to obtain that look

Tags: html, media-queries

I'm new to programming and I would appreciate some help.

I have the code on codepen.
Here is the codepen link:https://codepen.io/Oblivion37/pen/LYzZEmN;
I had to use two media queries because I didn't know how to do it in a different way to be responsive and decent-looking. Before that, I tried to put just one media query with the display of block, but then I couldn't specify a gap xd.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .text {
        background: rgb(206, 195, 195);
        flex-basis: 30%;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        max-width: 70rem;
      }
      header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      @media (max-width: 40em) {
        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width: 40em) {
        .text {
          margin-bottom: 3em;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab sapiente
          harum nam qui voluptate soluta reiciendis repudiandae quibusdam
          voluptatem. Nisi harum voluptatem quaerat dicta quae labore error, id
          asperiores architecto, distinctio cupiditate repellat repellendus,
          debitis voluptates ipsum recusandae omnis corrupti!i harum voluptatem
          quaerat dicta quae labore error, id asperiores architecto, distinctio
          cupiditate repellat repellendus, debitis voluptates ipsum rei harum
          voluptatem quaerat dicta quae labore error, id asperiores architecto,
          distinctio cupiditate repellat repellendus, debitis voluptates ipsum
          rei harum voluptatem quaerat dicta quae labore error, id asperiores
          architecto, distinctio cupiditate repellat repellendus, debitis
          voluptates ipsum re
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque
          consectetur beatae illum amet praesentium laboriosam officia, eligendi
          cupiditate repudiandae, alias quia id odio accusamus. Laudantium?
        </div>

        <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo facilis,
          sapiente mollitia itaque et, vel est repudiandae neque voluptatum quis
          qui nulla ullam ea. Nihil natus est similique aliquid velit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your CSS can be reduced to:

```
  @media (max-width: 40em) {
    .container {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .text {
      margin-bottom: 3em;
    }
  }
```

(Note: `display: flex` is inherited from the regular CSS rules, and you don't need to have separate media queries if the condition is identical.)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful, but why can't i use gap for example? it should work if flex-direction is column and the flex get inherited, right?

Comment: I was only talking about how to optimize your existing CSS rules - in the ones for which you had media queries, there was no gap or similar.